# Jupyter Notebook import not working after recent update

Tags: matplotlib, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I recently used the following command to update my jupyter packages `conda update --all` and from then on my visualization libraries wont import(matplotlib and seaborn). I used `conda install <pkg>` even then it wouldnt. So I reinstalled anaconda3 but same problem persists...

I tried to view sys.executable and found that it was not referencing my python lib in anaconda but in python [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cd8S.png)

`'c:\\python38\\python.exe'` So i used `pip3 install matplotlib` and matplotlib worked. I want my jupyter to reference to its own lib stack as I cannot install all libraries in python. I want the jupyter to read packages from this path : `C:\Users\princ\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages` because all anaconda libraries are there. How do I do it? Help me please. *The problem is jupyter is referencing python package folder and not pre installed packages in anaconda*

> SYS.PATH:

```
 'c:\\python38\\python38.zip',
 'c:\\python38\\DLLs',
 'c:\\python38\\lib',
 'c:\\python38',
 '',
 'C:\\Users\\princ\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages',
 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages',
 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
 'C:\\Users\\princ\\.ipython']
```

> jupyter kernelspec list

```
  python3    c:\python38\share\jupyter\kernels\python3
```

Comment: not just visualization libraries but libraries that are not installed by pip(python) wont import. conda has all libraries pre installed but wont import

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried running pip using directly the python executable with

```
python.exe -m pip install <pkg>
```

I don't know if there is a similar way to do it with `conda`

Comment: I did pip3 install <pkg> in cmd home dir... The problem is jupyter is referencing python package folder and not pre installed packages in anaconda